# findAll() on eager loaded models in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

The following does not work, where `Group` and `User` models have a N:M relationship:

```
var user_list = ["bob", "alice", "carol"];

Group.find({ where: { id: 1 }, include: [ { model: User, as: 'users' }]).then(function(group) {

    // Find group users that are also in user_list
    group.users.findAll({ where: { name: user_list }).then(function(affectedRows) {
        // Do stuff with affectedRows
    });

   // Find group users not in user_list
   group.users.findAll({ where: { name: { not: user_list } } }).then(function(affectedRows) {
        // Do stuff with affectedRows
   });

});
```

The error is:

> Possibly unhandled TypeError: Object [object
>   SequelizeInstance],[object SequelizeInstance],[object
>   SequelizeInstance],[object SequelizeInstance],[object
>   SequelizeInstance],[object SequelizeInstance],[object
>   SequelizeInstance],[object SequelizeInstance],[object
>   SequelizeInstance],[object SequelizeInstance],[object
>   SequelizeInstance],[object SequelizeInstance] has no method 'findAll'

I am trying to get a UNION and EXCEPT based off a given list. Is there a way to do this without making Sequelize use raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

`group.users` is an array of rows - not a model you can call methods on.

If you want to filter the users you should use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and do the filtering in plain javascript